# Can you subtract a line from an area?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I'm trying to find the probability of C, and I learned the probability is the area by the uniform law. The thing is I get a line from C. Did I find the wrong area or is there a way to subtract a line from the area?

[image]

Comment: Not really, if you are asking for area, there will be no change. It is possible for both numbers to land on that line, but it has probability 0.

Comment: One fourth of the area, I would say. However, yes, the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $x=y$ is a null set of this probability.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat this question as asking "what is the area of the line $y=x$ in $[0,2]\times[0,2]$" intuitively. Since this line segment possesses no area, the probability must be $0.$